# What is the Style of Theorem Proofs in Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

When we prove a theorem in set theory, do we have to prove in a formal first-order logic system? As theorems from set theory are typically represented in symbolic logic, and the language for set theory itself is highly formal, I guess we are not going to prove theorems using informal languages as in real analysis or linear algebra.

For instance, given the next four axioms:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\textrm{The Axiom of Equality:}\ \forall x \forall y \left[x = y \longrightarrow \forall z\left(x\in z \longleftrightarrow y \in z\right)\right]\\
&\textrm{The Axiom of Extensionality:}\ \forall x \forall y\left[x = y \longleftrightarrow \forall u\left(u\in x \longleftrightarrow u \in y\right)\right]\\
&\textrm{The Axiom of Existence:}\ \exists z \left(z = \emptyset\right)\\
&\textrm{The Axiom of Pairing:}\ \forall x \forall y \exists z \left(z = \left\{x,y\right\}\right),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
how to construct a proof for the following theorem:
\begin{equation}
\forall x \forall y \exists z \left(z = \langle x,y\rangle\right).
\end{equation}
Could anyone write a proof for this example to let me know how formal I should be in set theory?

Comment: I'd say that theorems of set theory are essentially identical to theorems of real analysis.

Comment: @Gae.S. Do we use a lot of informal statements to establish a proof?

Comment: Theorems of set theory can surely be expressed discoursively, at least for the foundational topics. In fact, if set theory could not be spoken about discoursively, perhaps we should use something else as a foundation of (most of) mathematics.

Comment: The point of a proof is not to be read by machines, but by other people who are expected to read more people's proofs. As a starting point, I suggest you gather some textbooks and see how typical proofs are done. Once you're comfortable with replicating those you may explore around the level of formality that suits you better.

Comment: Proofs of basic facts such as the one you cite are part of the early development of the subject. Similarly in, say, group theory, the first few propositions are important facts that you'll need, and the proofs are very 'close to the metal'. In set theory, this goes on longer. You (your prof, your text's author, your class) are building up a fund of theorems in a formal system, so the proofs are formal deductions. Once you've seen that you can define familiar constructs such as ordered pair, function, and more, you can use shorthands for them and prove theorems in a more typical, informal way.